# How to write to file that support tail -f

Tags: bash

Is it possible to write to file in one bash process and read it with tail in another (same way you can read system generated logs with `tail -f`.

I would like to open and continuously write something to file

```
vi /tmp/myfile
```

And in other terminal prints what was written to that file

```
tail -f /tmp/myfile
```

I've tried this, but tail doesn't print anything after I save changes in vi (only initial lines, before save).

Motivation:

In my toy project. I would like to build shared clipboard using [pipeto.me](https://pipeto.me) service. Where I would write to my file continuously and all changes captured by tail would be piped to curl. Something like watch log example from pipeto.me

`tail -f logfile | curl -T- -s https://pipeto.me/2xrGcZtQ`.

But instead of logfile it will watch my file, where I would write in vi

But apart from solving my problem, I'm looking for general answer if something like this is possible with vi and tail.

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to put `:w` for it to tail? That's just a shot in the dark though. I have no idea besides that one.

Comment: What is your goal? You can make a snapshot (copy) of the original file, monitor the file for changes and show the differences, it that something you want?

Comment: This really reeks of an [XY Problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Manually editing a file is not guaranteed to append stuff at the end of an existing file, which is all that `tail -f` is really capable of handling. What is the task you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's just toy project. I would like to build shared clipboard using pipeto.me service. Where I would write to file continuously and all changes captured by tail would be piped to curl. Something like watch log example from pipeto.me `tail -f logfile | curl -T- -s https://pipeto.me/2xrGcZtQ`. But instead of logfile it will *watch* my file, where I would write in vi.

Comment: @tripleee. Yes, I've described it XY problem way. :). But really solving problem is in this case secondary (as it's just a toy project). I'm more interested in explanation why this doesn't work (I'm curious person).

Comment: I would use `watch` instead and compare against a previously saved copy of the file, then use `diff` to pull out the changes. `tail -f` seems like completely the wrong approach here.

Comment: I will try watch and diff. Thanks for leading the way.

Comment: Use tail -F, that follows the file by name instead of inode id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cat command, by changing its output stream as /tmp/file that is whatever you type will be added to myfile,

```
cat > /tmp/myfile;
#input-> add text(standard input by default is set as keyboard)
#typing...
```

And to print the file with tail command with -F as argument,

```
tail -F /tmp/file; #-F -> output appended data as the file grows and with retry
#output-> input given to file
#typing....
```

Writing text to file with vim,

```
vi /tmp/file;
#typing...
#:w -> write text to file
tail -F /tmp/file;
#
#typing...
```

When you write to your file using vim, it **doesn't write(save) it instantly** as you type, instead when you exit the insert mode and save the file explicitly(:w), it is then the output of tail will be updated.

Hence you can use a plugin like Autosaveplugin which could help to save automatically, to display logs synchronously.

Comment: Actually `vim` will work fine when your `:w` (write) the buffer. Example: `touch log; tail -f log` (change to different terminal) `vim /path/to/log` (add stuff then) `:w` and the text will be shown by `tail`.

Comment: Yes, vim would work, I meant it won't show logs synchronously, as you add text until you write it manually when you want to update.

Comment: Gotcha... you are correct. Your redirect solution is the right one. You can also redirect `stdout`, etc.. to write to `/tmp/file` and then anything written to `stdout` while the redirect is in place will appear.

Comment: There should be `cat > /tmp/file;` instead of `cat > /tmp/myfile;`. But appart from that, this solution works for me. Thanks.